# In java, how to convert char class expressions to char array

Tags: arrays, regex, class, char, expression

Given a char class expressions, like "[A-Z][0-9]", is there a parser that can take this expression and return a char array that contains all the characters in the range?

like:

```
char[] result = RequiredServiceClass.parse ("[A-Z][0-9]abc");
```

So result will contain

```
{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c'}
```

Comment: This is not regex problem and your input is malformed also since `abc` is not a character class

Comment: What are all the possible inputs according to your needs? For as far as I know there is no such parser.

Answer (score 1):

You regex is not a single character class expression, it is matching one character from `A-Z` followed by one from `0-9` followed by the string literal `abc`.

It is not mentioned the intended use for this, but unless you are using it to write a regex tester or similar, it seems like a somewhat backwards usage of regex.

But if you really want to get the subset of characters in a charset that matches a single regex character class you could use something along the lines of:

```
public static char[] matchesInCharset(String regexCharClass, String charset) {
    // Append + to speed things up by matching consecutive ranges such as A-Z.
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regexCharClass + "+").matcher(charset);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (m.find())
        sb.append(m.group(0));

    char[] result = new char[sb.length()];
    sb.getChars(0, sb.length(), result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Example usage for ascii chars 0-255:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Make charset of all ascii characters.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
        sb.append((char)i); 

    String charset = sb.toString();
    char[] result = matchesInCharset("[A-Z0-9abc]", charset);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, a, b, c]
```

**Note:** If the charset is static you could obviously include it in the `matchesInCharset`, just make sure you don't generate it every time you use the method.